# Count the number of vowels occurring in all the substrings of given string

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am looking at this challenge:

> Given a string of length *N* of lowercase characters containing 0 or more vowels, the task is to find the count of vowels that occurred in all the substrings of the given string.
>
> #### Example
>
> ```
> Input: str = "abc" 
> Output: 3
> ```
>
> The given string "abc" contains only one vowel = 'a'.
> Substrings of "abc" are
>
> ```
> {"a", "b", "c", "ab", "bc", "abc"}
> ```
>
> Hence, the sum of occurrences of the vowel(s) in these strings is:
>
> ```
> 3
> ```
>
> ('a' occurred 3 times).

How to solve the above problem in O(*N*) time complexity ?

Comment: You're only going to be able to visit each character in the string once (well, a constant number of times) to achieve O(N). This means you'll need to be able to determine the total count of a character appearing in all substrings based only on its position within the string. Then you just add that value for each vowel you find in the string by passing through the string once. To determine that count, I suggest you work out the total substrings containing each character for, e.g., strings up to 7 in length to see the pattern that emerges and write a formula based on that pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some elements to use in the algorithm:

Let's first count how many *substrings* can be formed from a string (ignoring vowel counts):

```
"a" => {"a"} => 1
"ab" => {"ab", "a", "b"} => 1+2 = 3
"abc" => {"abc", "ab", "bc", "a", "b", "c"} => 1+2+3 = 6
"abcd" => {"abcd", "abc", "bcd", "ab", "bc", "cd", "a", "b", "c", "d"} => 1+2+3+4 = 10
 ...
```

The pattern is 1+2+3+...+, where  is the length of the string, which is (+1)/2

Now let's take a string that just has *one* vowel: "klmnopqrst". Then the answer consists of counting the number of substrings which have this vowel.

We know there are 10(10+1)/2 = 55 substrings in total, but many of those counted subtrings do not have a vowel. None of the subtrings of "klmn" have a vowel. There are 4(4+1)/2 = 10 such subtrings. Also none of the subtrings of "pqrst" have a vowel. There are 5(5+1)/2 = 15 such substrings. All other substrings have the vowel. So we can make the subtraction... the output should be 55 - 10 - 15 = 30.

Therefore the general principle is: for each vowel in the input, determine how many substrings do *not* include that vowel -- by counting the number of substrings at the *left*, and those at the *right* of the vowel. This gives us a clue about the number of substrings that *do* include that vowel -- by subtracting the non-cases from the total number of substrings.

If we do this for each vowel, we will have counted the total occurrences of vowels in all the substrings.

Here is that algorithm expressed in pseudo code:

```pascal
function occurrence(str):
    n := length(str)
    total := 0
    allcount := n * (n + 1) // 2
    for i := 1 to n:
        if str[i] is a vowel:
            total = total + allcount - (i - 1) * i / 2 - (n - 1 - i) * (n - i) / 2
    return total
```

NB: note that -- as is common in pseudo code -- `i` is a *position* (starting at 1), not a zero-based index.

Comment: I would have interpreted OPs description to mean "ae" => {"ae", "a", "e"} => 2 + 1 + 1 = 4

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted in my first paragraphs to just count substrings, not individual vowels, as that is a step in the algorithm to take. I corrected the text, and made the example with "abc", ignoring any distinction  based on vowels. I believe the derived formula and algorithm are fine.

Comment: @trincot nice explanation. Now I get it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

(In case [trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68243604/2034787) is not enough.)

Each vowel appears in `(l + 1) * (r + 1)` substrings, where `l` is the number of characters to the left of the vowel and `r` the number of characters on the right of the vowel.

```
Example 1:

"abc"

'a': (0 + 1) * (2 + 1) = 3

Total: 3


Example 2:

"ae"

'a': (0 + 1) * (1 + 1) = 2
'e': (1 + 1) * (0 + 1) = 2

Total: 4
```

Comment: how did you come up with (l+1)*(r+1) this formula ?

Comment: @Rajatkashyap we fix the vowel as the only character in the substring. Then we extend left `l` times for each extension of the substring one of `r` times to the right. The `+ 1` is for extending `l` or `r` zero times.